# How to save Received Messages From Gsm Modem to your Mysql Database?

Tags: vb.net, mysql-workbench

I am trying to save received sms from my modem to MySQL database, and I am using MySQL Workbench for my database.

Here's my functionalities:
1. Auto detect modem
2. Connect modem
3. Send Messages

4. Read Messages
5. Handles (SerialPort Data received)

Here's the Code:
**1. Auto Detect Modem**

```
'Some Imports
Imports System.Management
Imports System.Threading
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient

Public Class Form1
    Dim result() As String
    Dim query As String
    Dim rcvdata As String = ""

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim ports() As String
        ports = Split(ModemsConnected(), "***")
        For i As Integer = 0 To ports.Length - 2
            ComboBox1.Items.Add(ports(i))
        Next
    End Sub

    Public Function ModemsConnected() As String
        Dim modems As String = ""
        Try
            Dim searcher As New ManagementObjectSearcher("root\CIMV2", "SELECT * FROM Win32_POTSModem")

            For Each queryObj As ManagementObject In searcher.Get()
                If queryObj("Status") = "OK" Then
                    modems = modems & (queryObj("AttachedTo") & " - " & queryObj("Description") & "***")
                End If
            Next
        Catch err As ManagementException
            MessageBox.Show("An error occurred while querying for WMI data: " & err.Message)
            Return ""
        End Try
        Return modems
    End Function

'Show Detected or Available modem
    Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedValueChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedValueChanged
        Label1.Text = Trim(Mid(ComboBox1.Text, 1, 5))
    End Sub
```

**2. Connect/Disconnect Modem**

```
    'button connect
            Private Sub btnConnect_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnConnect.Click
                Try
                    With SerialPort1
                        .PortName = Label1.Text
                        .BaudRate = 9600
                        .Parity = IO.Ports.Parity.None
                        .DataBits = 8
                        .StopBits = IO.Ports.StopBits.One
                        .Handshake = IO.Ports.Handshake.None
                        .RtsEnable = True
                        .ReceivedBytesThreshold = 1
                        .NewLine = vbCr
                        .ReadTimeout = 1000
                        .Open()
                    End With
                    If SerialPort1.IsOpen Then
                        Label3.Visible = True
                        btnDisconnect.Visible = True
                        Label3.Text = "Connected - Port " & Label1.Text & " is used"
                    Else
                        Label3.Text = "Got some Error, Check your connection with your Modem."
                    End If
                Catch ex As Exception
                    MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Text Messaging")
                End Try
            End Sub

'button Disconnect
    Private Sub btnDisconnect_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnDisconnect.Click
        Try
            If SerialPort1.IsOpen Then
                With SerialPort1
                    .Close()
                    .Dispose()
                    Label1.Visible = False
                    Label3.Visible = False
                    btnDisconnect.Visible = False
                    ListView1.Items.Clear()
                End With
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
```

**3. Send Messages**

```
Private Sub btnSend_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSend.Click
        Dim query As String
        Try
            Connection()
            query = "INSERT INTO thesis.tblsentitems (PhoneNumber, message) VALUES('" & txtNumber.Text & "', '" & txtMessage.Text & "')"
            sqlcmd = New MySqlCommand(query, conn)
            sqlreader = sqlcmd.ExecuteReader

            With SerialPort1
                .Write("at" & vbCrLf)
                Threading.Thread.Sleep(200)
                .Write("at+cmgf=1" & vbCrLf)
                Threading.Thread.Sleep(200)
                .Write("at+cmgs=" & Chr(34) & txtNumber.Text & Chr(34) & vbCrLf)
                .Write(txtMessage.Text & Chr(26))
                Threading.Thread.Sleep(200)

            End With
            If rcvdata.ToString.Contains(">") Then
                MsgBox("Message Succesfully Sent")
                conn.Close()
            Else
                MsgBox("Got some error!")
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Text Messaging")
        End Try
    End Sub
```

**4. Read Messages**

```
    Private Sub btnReadsms_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnReadsms.Click
        Try
            With SerialPort1
                .Write("AT" & vbCrLf)
                Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
                .Write("AT+CMGF=1" & vbCrLf)
                Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
                .Write("AT+CPMS=""SM""" & vbCrLf)
                Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
                .Write("AT+CMGL=""ALL""" & vbCrLf)
                Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
                'MsgBox(rcvdata.ToString)
                readmsg()
            End With
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub

'Save Received message to ListView1 
    Private Sub readmsg()
        Try
            Dim lineoftext As String
            Dim i As Integer
            Dim arytextfile() As String
            lineoftext = rcvdata.ToString
            arytextfile = Split(lineoftext, "+CMGL", , CompareMethod.Text)
            For i = 1 To UBound(arytextfile)
                Dim input As String = arytextfile(i)
                Dim pattern As String = "(:)|(,"")|("","")"
                result = Regex.Split(input, pattern)
                Dim concat() As String
                With ListView1.Items.Add("null")
                    'for index
                    .SubItems.AddRange(New String() {result(2).ToString})
                    'for status
                    .SubItems.AddRange(New String() {result(4).ToString})
                    'for number
                    Dim my_string, position As String
                    my_string = result(6)
                    position = my_string.Length - 2
                    my_string = my_string.Remove(position, 2)
                    .SubItems.Add(my_string)
                    'for date and time
                    concat = New String() {result(8)}
                    .SubItems.AddRange(concat)
                    'for message
                    Dim lineoftexts As String
                    Dim arytextfiles() As String
                    lineoftexts = arytextfile(i)
                    arytextfiles = Split(lineoftexts, "+32", , CompareMethod.Text)
                    .SubItems.Add(arytextfiles(1))
                End With
            Next
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
```

**5. Handles (SerialPort Data received)**

```
Private Sub SerialPort1_datareceived(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs) Handles SerialPort1.DataReceived
    Dim datain As String = ""
    Dim numbytes As Integer = SerialPort1.BytesToRead
    For i As Integer = 1 To numbytes
        datain &= Chr(SerialPort1.ReadChar)
    Next
    test(datain)
End Sub

Private Sub test(ByVal indata As String)
    rcvdata &= indata
End Sub
```

> Hope someone can Help, please... :/

Comment: Help with *what*?  There is nothing related to MySQL there. See [Ask]

Comment: SORRY sir, I am a newbie. I will post some attempt to save the received message.

Comment: We do not need your whole project, just the part you need help with.  See [MCVE]

Comment: Connection()

        query = "INSERT INTO tblInbox(index, status, number, date, message) VALUES('" & ListView1.FocusedItem.SubItems(1).Text & "', '" & ListView1.FocusedItem.SubItems(2).Text & "', '" & ListView1.FocusedItem.SubItems(3).Text & "', '" & ListView1.FocusedItem.SubItems(4).Text & "', '" & ListView1.FocusedItem.SubItems(5).Text & "')"

        sqlcmd = New MySqlCommand(query, conn)
        sqlreader = sqlcmd.ExecuteReader

Comment: that's the code of my button save sir. and here's the error.

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax, check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'index, statuc, number, data, message) VALUES('0', 'REC READ', '+63907231323',' at line 1